# Scala criterion equivalent

Tags: scala, haskell, benchmarking, haskell-criterion

Is there a Scala (or Java, I guess) equivalent of [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion)? I'm not just talking about a benchmarking library:  check out what criterion does for HTML results.

Comment: Check http://bos.github.com/criterion/ for the reports, and statistical breakdown/kernel density plots.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. As far as I can tell as of 2012-Nov-26 Criterion has not been ported to any other language ecosystem. There's no fundamental reason for this.

Comment: and ever since ?